# Log Analytics retention policy and querying on logs

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor

I would like to know how can we address this scenario in Azure Log Analytics where I need to generate Kube-audit logs of different cluster every week and also retain these logs for approx 400 days. Now storing it over Log Analytics will cost me more and its not an optimized architecture as I will not be require that so often. So I would like to know from experts whats the best way to design the architecture, where we get the kube audit logs which can be retained for 400 days and be available for querying when required without incurring too much cost.
PS: I also heard in my team that querying 400 days logs always times out in KQL.

Comment: The majority of log data in Kubernetes is erased after a set amount of time, which varies depending on the type of log and your logging parameters. As a result, you'll need to export previous log data to an external logging platform if you wish to keep it for a long time.

Comment: You'll need an external log collection, analysis, and management platform like `LogDNA` to get the most out of Kubernetes logging.

Comment: well I am looking for 400 days of data.. Kube audit logs in Azure mention 2 years of retention, Cant I export the log data to a storage account or something and then query from there?

Answer (score 1):

**Log analytics offerings:**
Log analytics now provides the capability to manage several service tiers at table scope. Setting your data as archive, with no query capabilities at a much lower cost. offering spans for up to 7 years.

when needed, you can choose to elevate a subset of your data into the Analytics offering, providing you the capability to query it. The action of elevating your data is denoted as - "Search jobs"

Another option is to elevate an entire period in time to the Analytic offering, they call it - "Restore logs".

Table's different service tiers -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-retention-archive?tabs=api-1%2Capi-2

Search job offering -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/search-jobs?tabs=api-1%2Capi-2%2Capi-3

Restore logs -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/restore?tabs=api-1%2Capi-2

all are under public preview.

both offerings - Search jobs and Restore logs provides you the capability to engage your data on demand, can't comment or suggest regarding the actual cost.

**Azure data explorer solution:**
Another option is to use Azure storage to hold your data (as an example), Azure data explorer provides the capability to create an external table, that table is a logical view on top of your data, the data itself is kept outside of the ADX cluster. you can query your data by using ADX, expect degradation in query performance.

ADX external table offering -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/externaltables

Comment: The archive feature is currently in public preview and can only be set at the table level, not at the workspace level. DO you know what is table level in here? If I am concerned with the kube-audit logs which table should I consider?

Comment: There is no table level for kube-audit if you are using container insights solution, it seems its being persisted in external storage and not over an LA Workspace.
Reference for container insights data availability - 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/monitor-aks#collect-resource-logs
For that use case best option will be to use ADX external table.

You could always write your own solution which will write those logs programmatic and use LA data collector api to send them directly to the LA data plane.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api

Comment: Ok, but you mentioned ADX will be with degraded performance..is there a way we can build a synapse solution on top of storage account for better quyering performance.

Comment: So do you know if kube audit will supported in future for search job /restore logs

Comment: Can't say, it will require the solution to support it from the get-go, it seems they are very explicit with stating they are going to keep it outside of LA.

Comment: cant say for Synapse or solution to support audit logs?

Comment: You can ingest Kube-Audit to the LA Azure Diagnostic table. go to your cluster -> Diagnostic settings -> choose kube audit and set your workspace as destination. Azure Diagnostic table is shared across multiple resource centric experiences in Azure, the different sources can be distinguished by reviewing the category column.

Comment: If you are willing to change the retention for the entire table you can switch its plan to Basic (Basic plan is limited to a small set of tables and all of Custom logs tables, but it might work for this one, worth to check). this will limit your retention to 8 days and you can set your archive period for up to 7 years (Just make sure you set it correctly). then you can use Search results on demand and to address the appropriate category ("kube-audit" in our case) in your search query.

Comment: Are you talking about Search job public preview feature above..I didn't get you.. my simple limitation on storing all my logs in log analytic is that it times out on querying and it's also costly while storing logs for 400 days..which is approx 15 to size.. again I do not need to query 400 days logs everyday..it's once/twice a year activity but my querying on kube audit sometime even fails for 12 hrs time span.. what you will recommed

Comment: Here is the link of kusto query which fails...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363173/modifying-kusto-to-get-the-logs-output/72373530#72373530