# Modifying Kusto to get the logs output

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have my below kql which when ran in Log Analytics give me the right result. But Now I have moved my logs to a storage account and created an ADX external table to query the same logs using Kusto. however I am finding it difficult to Query as same query wont work and will need some modification. I would need help if someone can advice on what all changes should I do in existing Kusto to get the same result.

In log Analytics this works:

```
"AzureDiagnostics
            | where Category == 'kube-audit'
            | where TimeGenerated between (datetime("$querystart") .. datetime("$queryend")) 
            | where (strlen(log_s) >= 32000 
                and not(log_s contains \"aksService\") 
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:crossplane-system:crossplane\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:elastic-system:elastic-operator\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:internal-services:cert-manager-cainjector\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:internal-services:spinnaker\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:daemon-set-controller\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:deployment-controller\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:endpoint-controller\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:replicaset-controller\")
                and not(log_s contains \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:statefulset-controller\"))
                or strlen(log_s) < 32000
            | extend op = parse_json(log_s) 
            | where not(tostring(op.verb) in (\"list\", \"get\", \"watch\"))
            | where not(tostring(op.user.username) hasprefix \"system:\")
            | where not(tostring(op.user.username) in (\"hcpService\", \"aksService\", \"aksProblemDetector\", \"readinessChecker\", \"nodeclient\", \"masterclient\"))
            | where substring(tostring(op.responseStatus.code), 0, 1) == \"2\"
            | where not(tostring(op.requestURI) in (\"/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1/selfsubjectaccessreviews\"))
            | extend user = op.user.username
            | extend decision = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.annotations)).[\"authorization.k8s.io/decision\"])
            | extend requestURI = tostring(op.requestURI)
            | extend name = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.objectRef)).name)
            | extend namespace = tostring(parse_json(tostring(op.objectRef)).namespace)
            | extend verb = tostring(op.verb)
            | project TimeGenerated, SubscriptionId, ResourceId, namespace, name, requestURI, verb, decision, ['user']
            | order by TimeGenerated asc"
```

and the output in Log Analytics for query

```
AzureDiagnostics
            | where Category == 'kube-audit'
```

On exporting to storage account and then creating an External table in ADX over it, I dont see the same schema, the result I have in ADX external table for kube-audit is something like this:

```
   "operationName": Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/diagnosticLogs/Read,
    "category": kube-audit,
    "ccpNamespace": 5c40f,
    "resourceId": /SUBSCRIPTIONS/53AEB/RESOURCEGROUPS/AZURE-DEV/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/AZURE-DEV,
    "properties": {
        "log": "{\"kind\":\"Event\",\"apiVersion\":\"audit.k8s.io/v1\",\"level\":\"Request\",\"auditID\":\"d80ca0b72-75eaf\",\"stage\":\"ResponseComplete\",\"requestURI\":\"/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/events/deployments/api/scale\",\"verb\":\"get\",\"user\":{\"username\":\"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:horizontal-pod-autoscaler\",\"uid\":\"d5d7-ba1cfb172033\",\"groups\":[\"system:serviceaccounts\",\"system:serviceaccounts:kube-system\",\"system:authenticated\"]},\"sourceIPs\":[\"100.11.11.0\"],\"userAgent\":\"kube-controller-manager/v1.22.6 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/0795921/system:serviceaccount:kube-system:horizontal-pod-autoscaler\",\"objectRef\":{\"resource\":\"deployments\",\"namespace\":\"events\",\"name\":\"api\",\"apiGroup\":\"apps\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"subresource\":\"scale\"},\"responseStatus\":{\"metadata\":{},\"code\":200},\"requestReceivedTimestamp\":\"2022-05-23T13:44:59.985416Z\",\"stageTimestamp\":\"2022-05-23T13:45:00.002107Z\",\"annotations\":{\"authorization.k8s.io/decision\":\"allow\",\"authorization.k8s.io/reason\":\"RBAC: allowed by ClusterRoleBinding \\\"system:controller:horizontal-pod-autoscaler\\\" of ClusterRole \\\"system:controller:horizontal-pod-autoscaler\\\" to ServiceAccount \\\"horizontal-pod-autoscaler/cfxyz\\\"\"}}\n",
        "stream": "stdout",
        "pod": "kube-apiserver-7d-q6v"
    },
    "time": 2022-05-23T13:45:00Z,
    "Cloud": AzureCloud,
    "Environment": prod,
    "UnderlayClass": hcp-underlay,
    "UnderlayName": hcp-underlay-norteurope-cx-624,
```

External table schema:

```
"TableName": logsKube,
"Schema": operationName:string,category:string,ccpNamespace:string,resourceId:string,properties:dynamic,['time']:datetime,Cloud:string,Environment:string,UnderlayClass:string,UnderlayName:string,
"DatabaseName": logsstorage,
"Folder": ,
"DocString": ,
```

How can I run the above query in ADX to get the result?

Comment: The obvious answer is that you should align the external table schema to the original table schema. The supplied code is irrelevant.  The supplied data sample is not clear. You haven't supplied the external table schema / definition

Comment: the supplied schema at last is of external table. and for Log Analytics that is pretty standard for all projects.

Comment: Schema is a structure composite of fields' names and types. I'm guessing that you defined your external table with a single dynamic field, but it's only a guess because your data sample is partial and out of context. I have no idea where you copied it from.

Comment: so what I did was created diagnostic settings to send kube audit to Storage account and then in ADX created the external table as you suggessted on top of the container in the Storage account created above. In schema definition in ADX , I selected the sample row which we got in the schema selection and thats it.

Comment: How you would do?

Comment: I didn't understand the last question ("How you would do?"). Other than that - I understand you was able to create an external table with the same schema as the original table. Is everything working now for you as expected?

Comment: If you start creating an External table, it will give you the sample rows to select the schema.. I selected one of the rows and  thats how the schema of the table is defined. Its not working for me. SO what is actually happening here is that in diagnostic settings , if you send jube-audit logs to Log Analytics then you have a different schema and if you send it to Storage Account..you have different schema..

Comment: and now this external table in ADX is on storage account and hence different schema

Comment: **Please share the schema of your external table - `.show external table ['myExternalTable'] cslschema` and the error message you're getting when running your query**

Comment: added the external table schema.. here in properties I have log and their values as shown in example above. I need to write the above KQL on this schema in ADX.

Comment: Your schema lacks fields that are being referenced in your query. **Seriously, how do you expect it to work?**. If you haven't exported the required fields do it. If you do have those fields in your files, create an external table with schema that reflect them.

Comment: even the field names changes when you export to Storage account from diagnostic settings.. in LA its log_s while in SA its just log.. there is not just field which is missing even the schema changes on exporting kube audit logs at two different places

Answer (score 0):

Create the external table manually, using the original columns' names.
[Create and alter Azure Storage external tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-tables-azurestorage-azuredatalake#schema)

Should be somthing like that:

```
.create-or-alter external table logsKube (TenantId:string,TimeGenerated:datetime,ResourceId:string,Category:string,ResourceGroup:string,SubscriptionId:string,ResourceProvider:string,Resource:string,ResourceType:string,OperationName:string,ResultType:string,CorrelationId:string,ResultDescription:string,Tenant_g:string,JobId_g:string,RunbookName_s:string,StreamType_s:string,Caller_s:string,requestUri_s:string,Level:string,DurationMs:string,CallerIPAddress:string,OperationVersion:string,ResultSignature:string,id_s:string,status_s:string,LogicalServerName_s:string,Message:string,clientInfo_s:string,httpStatusCode_d:string,identity_claim_appid_g:string,identity_claim_http_schemas_microsoft_com_identity_claims_objectidentifier_g:string,userAgent_s:string,ruleName_s:string,identity_claim_http_schemas_xmlsoap_org_ws_2005_05_identity_claims_upn_s:string,systemId_g:string,isAccessPolicyMatch_b:string,EventName_s:string,httpMethod_s:string,subnetId_s:string,type_s:string,instanceId_s:string,macAddress_s:string,vnetResourceGuid_g:string,direction_s:string,subnetPrefix_s:string,primaryIPv4Address_s:string,conditions_sourcePortRange_s:string,priority_d:string,conditions_destinationPortRange_s:string,conditions_destinationIP_s:string,conditions_None_s:string,conditions_sourceIP_s:string,httpVersion_s:string,matchedConnections_d:string,startTime_t:string,endTime_t:string,DatabaseName_s:string,clientIP_s:string,host_s:string,requestQuery_s:string,sslEnabled_s:string,clientPort_d:string,httpStatus_d:string,receivedBytes_d:string,sentBytes_d:string,timeTaken_d:string,resultDescription_ErrorJobs_s:string,resultDescription_ChildJobs_s:string,identity_claim_http_schemas_microsoft_com_identity_claims_scope_s:string,workflowId_s:string,resource_location_s:string,resource_workflowId_g:string,resource_resourceGroupName_s:string,resource_subscriptionId_g:string,resource_runId_s:string,resource_workflowName_s:string,_schema_s:string,correlation_clientTrackingId_s:string,properties_sku_Family_s:string,properties_sku_Name_s:string,properties_tenantId_g:string,properties_enabledForDeployment_b:string,code_s:string,resultDescription_Summary_MachineId_s:string,resultDescription_Summary_ScheduleName_s:string,resultDescription_Summary_Status_s:string,resultDescription_Summary_StatusDescription_s:string,resultDescription_Summary_MachineName_s:string,resultDescription_Summary_TotalUpdatesInstalled_d:string,resultDescription_Summary_RebootRequired_b:string,resultDescription_Summary_TotalUpdatesFailed_d:string,resultDescription_Summary_InstallPercentage_d:string,resultDescription_Summary_StartDateTimeUtc_t:string,resource_triggerName_s:string,resultDescription_Summary_InitialRequiredUpdatesCount_d:string,properties_enabledForTemplateDeployment_b:string,resultDescription_Summary_EndDateTimeUtc_s:string,resultDescription_Summary_DurationInMinutes_s:string,resource_originRunId_s:string,properties_enabledForDiskEncryption_b:string,resource_actionName_s:string,correlation_actionTrackingId_g:string,resultDescription_Summary_EndDateTimeUtc_t:string,resultDescription_Summary_DurationInMinutes_d:string,conditions_protocols_s:string,identity_claim_ipaddr_s:string,ElasticPoolName_s:string,identity_claim_http_schemas_microsoft_com_claims_authnmethodsreferences_s:string,RunOn_s:string,query_hash_s:string,SourceSystem:string,MG:string,ManagementGroupName:string,Computer:string,RawData:string,certificatePolicyProperties_certificateProperties_subject_s:string,certificatePolicyProperties_certificateProperties_validityInMonths_d:string,certificatePolicyProperties_keyProperties_type_s:string,certificatePolicyProperties_keyProperties_size_d:string,certificatePolicyProperties_keyProperties_export_b:string,certificatePolicyProperties_secretProperties_type_s:string,certificatePolicyProperties_certificateIssuerProperties_name_s:string,error_state_d:string,location_s:string,Tenant_s:string,RecoveryJobDestination_s:string,RecoveryJobRPLocation_s:string,RecoveryLocationType_s:string,upstreamSourcePort_s:string,ProtectedContainerOSType_s:string,ProtectedContainerOSVersion_s:string,GatewayManagerVersion_s:string,targetResources_CertificateName_s:string,displayResourceId_s:string,executionClusterType_s:string,clientResponseTime_d:string,targetResources_NodeConfigurationName_s:string,targetResources_NodeId_g:string,targetResources_CredentialId_g:string,targetResources_CredentialName_s:string,targetResources_DscConfigurationName_s:string,targetResources_VariableId_g:string,targetResources_VariableName_s:string,targetResources_RunbookId_g:string,targetResources_RunbookName_s:string,targetResources_ModuleId_g:string,targetResources_ModuleName_s:string,targetResources_ScheduleId_g:string,targetResources_ScheduleName_s:string,clientInfo_TenantId_g:string,clientInfo_Issuer_s:string,clientInfo_ObjectId_g:string,clientInfo_AppId_g:string,targetResources_JobScheduleId_g:string,targetResources_JobName_s:string,clientInfo_IpAddress_s:string,clientInfo_PrincipalName_s:string,clientInfo_ClientRequestId_g:string,targetResources_Resource_s:string,targetResources_JobId_g:string,targetResources_JobName_g:string,clusterType_s:string,identity_claim_upn_s:string,DataCenterName_s:string,identity_claim_scp_s:string,identity_claim_unique_name_s:string,identity_claim_amr_s:string,identity_claim_oid_g:string,identity_claim_home_oid_g:string,removedAccessPolicy_Permissions_storage_s:string,replicationHealthErrors_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_topic_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_subject_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_eventType_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_eventTime_t:string,eventGridEventProperties_data_Id_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_data_VaultName_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_data_ObjectType_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_data_ObjectName_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_data_Version_s:string,eventGridEventProperties_dataVersion_s:string,properties_networkAcls_bypass_s:string,properties_networkAcls_defaultAction_s:string,properties_softDeleteRetentionInDays_d:string,error_number_d:string,Severity:string,user_defined_b:string,state_d:string,PolicyUniqueId_s:string,ProtectedContainerName_g:string,identity_claim_http_schemas_xmlsoap_org_ws_2005_05_identity_claims_name_s:string,retryHistory_s:string,network_s:string,nexthop_s:string,locprf_s:string,weight_s:string,path_s:string,addressfamily_s:string,ClientOperationId_g:string,CorrelationRequestId_g:string,Region_s:string,ScaleUnit_s:string,ActivityId_g:string,EventTimeString_s:string,EventProperties_s:string,SKU_s:string,virtual_core_count_s:string,avg_cpu_percent_s:string,reserved_storage_mb_s:string,storage_space_used_mb_s:string,io_requests_s:string,io_bytes_read_s:string,io_bytes_written_s:string,timeOfOccurence_t:string,eventType_s:string,description_s:string,healthErrors_s:string,logId_g:string,removedAccessPolicy_TenantId_g:string,removedAccessPolicy_ObjectId_g:string,removedAccessPolicy_Permissions_keys_s:string,removedAccessPolicy_Permissions_secrets_s:string,removedAccessPolicy_Permissions_certificates_s:string,addedAccessPolicy_TenantId_g:string,addedAccessPolicy_ObjectId_g:string,addedAccessPolicy_Permissions_keys_s:string,addedAccessPolicy_Permissions_secrets_s:string,addedAccessPolicy_Permissions_certificates_s:string,addedAccessPolicy_Permissions_storage_s:string,properties_enableSoftDelete_b:string,JobOperationSubType_s:string,DataTransferredInMB_s:string,ProtectedInstanceCount_s:string,StorageConsumedInMBs_s:string,StorageType_s:string,StorageName_s:string,OldestRecoveryPointTime_s:string,OldestRecoveryPointLocation_s:string,LatestRecoveryPointTime_s:string,LatestRecoveryPointLocation_s:string,BackupItemFrontEndSize_s:string,StorageUniqueId_s:string,AlertConsolidationStatus_s:string,CountOfAlertsConsolidated_s:string,AlertRaisedOn_s:string,AlertCode_s:string,RecommendedAction_s:string,AlertUniqueId_s:string,AlertType_s:string,AlertStatus_s:string,AlertOccurrenceDateTime_s:string,AlertSeverity_s:string,TelemetryProperties_s:string,AdHocOrScheduledJob_s:string,affectedResourceId_s:string,JobUniqueId_g:string,JobOperation_s:string,JobStatus_s:string,JobFailureCode_s:string,JobStartDateTime_s:string,JobDurationInSecs_s:string,RecoveryJobRPDateTime_s:string,affectedResourceName_s:string,affectedResourceId_g:string,affectedResourceType_s:string,logId_d:string,DeploymentUnit_s:string,CloudStorageInBytes_s:string,ProtectedInstances_s:string,trustedService_s:string,OptionName_s:string,OptionDesiredState_s:string,OptionActualState_s:string,OptionDisableReason_s:string,IsDisabledBySystem_d:string,DatabaseDesiredMode_s:string,DatabaseActualMode_s:string,RegisteredContainerId_s:string,ProtectedServerType_s:string,ProtectedServerFriendlyName_s:string,BackupManagementServerUniqueId_s:string,BackupItemId_s:string,ProtectedServerName_s:string,ProtectionState_s:string,ProtectedServerUniqueId_s:string,exec_type_d:string,wait_category_s:string,total_query_wait_time_ms_d:string,max_query_wait_time_ms_d:string,is_parameterizable_s:string,statement_type_s:string,statement_key_hash_s:string,query_param_type_d:string,interval_start_time_d:string,interval_end_time_d:string,logical_io_writes_d:string,max_logical_io_writes_d:string,physical_io_reads_d:string,max_physical_io_reads_d:string,logical_io_reads_d:string,max_logical_io_reads_d:string,execution_type_d:string,count_executions_d:string,cpu_time_d:string,max_cpu_time_d:string,dop_d:string,max_dop_d:string,rowcount_d:string,max_rowcount_d:string,query_max_used_memory_d:string,max_query_max_used_memory_d:string,duration_d:string,max_duration_d:string,num_physical_io_reads_d:string,max_num_physical_io_reads_d:string,log_bytes_used_d:string,max_log_bytes_used_d:string,query_id_d:string,plan_id_d:string,query_plan_hash_s:string,statement_sql_handle_s:string,tags_displayName_s:string,error_code_s:string,error_message_s:string,start_utc_date_t:string,end_utc_date_t:string,wait_type_s:string,delta_max_wait_time_ms_d:string,delta_signal_wait_time_ms_d:string,delta_wait_time_ms_d:string,delta_waiting_tasks_count_d:string,LogBackupFrequency_s:string,LogBackupRetentionDuration_s:string,PolicyTimeZone_s:string,PolicyName_s:string,BackupFrequency_s:string,BackupTimes_s:string,BackupDaysOfTheWeek_s:string,DailyRetentionDuration_s:string,DailyRetentionTimes_s:string,ProtectedContainerFriendlyName_s:string,ProtectedContainerWorkloadType_s:string,ProtectedContainerName_s:string,ProtectedContainerProtectionState_s:string,ProtectedContainerLocation_s:string,ProtectedContainerType_s:string,listenerName_s:string,backendPoolName_s:string,backendSettingName_s:string,originalRequestUriWithArgs_s:string,transactionId_g:string,sslCipher_s:string,sslProtocol_s:string,sslClientVerify_s:string,sslClientCertificateFingerprint_s:string,sslClientCertificateIssuerName_s:string,serverRouted_s:string,serverStatus_s:string,serverResponseLatency_s:string,originalHost_s:string,EndpointName_s:string,Status_s:string,NodeId_g:string,NodeName_s:string,NodeComplianceStatus_s:string,DscReportId_g:string,DscReportStatus_s:string,LastSeenTime_t:string,ReportStartTime_t:string,ReportEndTime_t:string,ConfigurationMode_s:string,HostName_s:string,NumberOfResources_d:string,IPAddress:string,DscResourceId_s:string,DscResourceName_s:string,DscResourceStatus_s:string,DscModuleName_s:string,DscModuleVersion_s:string,DscConfigurationName_s:string,DscResourceDuration_d:string,ErrorCode_s:string,ErrorMessage_s:string,BackupItemProtectionState_s:string,BackupItemAppVersion_s:string,BackupItemUniqueId_s:string,BackupItemName_s:string,BackupItemFriendlyName_s:string,BackupItemType_s:string,BackupManagementType_s:string,ProtectedContainerUniqueId_s:string,PolicyUniqueId_g:string,timeStamp_t:string,lastRecoveryPoint_t:string,latestAppConsistentRecoveryPoint_t:string,replicatingDisksCount_d:string,uploadRPOInSeconds_d:string,uploadRPOUpdateTime_t:string,processedRPOInSeconds_d:string,processedRPOUpdateTime_t:string,EventId_d:string,VaultUniqueId_s:string,VaultName_s:string,AzureDataCenter_s:string,VaultTags_s:string,ResourceGroupName_s:string,StorageReplicationType_s:string,SchemaVersion_s:string,State_s:string,InstanceName_s:string,Value_s:string,ProviderName_s:string,TaskName_s:string,agentVersion_s:string,recoveryRegion_s:string,multiVmGroupId_g:string,multiVmGroupName_s:string,multiVmGroupCreateOption_s:string,recoveryNetworkId_s:string,lastHeartbeat_t:string,multiVmSyncStatus_s:string,targetVmNicDetails_s:string,recoveryServicesProviderId_g:string,replicationHealth_s:string,failoverHealth_s:string,name_s:string,id_g:string,primaryFabricName_s:string,recoveryFabricName_s:string,primaryFabricType_s:string,recoveryFabricType_s:string,primaryContainerName_s:string,recoveryContainerName_s:string,protectionState_s:string,activeLocation_s:string,policyName_s:string,replicationProviderName_s:string,osFamily_s:string,initialReplicationProgressPercentage_d:string,itemType_s:string,failoverHealthErrors_s:string,rpoInSeconds_d:string,lastRpoCalculatedTime_t:string,version_s:string,attrs_s:string,containerID_s:string,ccpNamespace_s:string,log_s:string,stream_s:string,pod_s:string,Cloud_s:string,Environment_s:string,UnderlayClass_s:string,UnderlayName_s:string,msg_s:string,AdditionalFields:string,Type:string,_ResourceId:string)
kind=storage 
dataformat=csv 
( 
   h@'abfss://filesystem@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/path;secretKey'
) 
with (includeHeaders=all)
```